# $_POST data does not work with ../ 1 up folder action

Tags: php, html, post, directory

My form $_POST data works perfectly fine when I put the action.php file in the same directly as in my index.php on my hosting, when I move the php file up 1 folder and into the includes folder like so:

```
<!-- This works perfectly fine -->
<form id="test" action="action.php"  method="POST" >

<!-- This does NOT pass the $_POST data but it goes to the php file and outputs the print test I put in the action.php file. so it is going where it needs to go but it is losing the POST data for some weird reason -->
<form id="test" action="../includes/action.php"  method="POST" >
```

Folder Structure that DOES work

```
(ROOT DIR)Test form
-js
-img
-index.php
-action.php
```

Folder Structure that DOES NOT work

```
(ROOT DIR) includes
- action.php
(ROOT DIR) Test form
-js
-img
-index.php
```

even set the includes folder persmissions to chmod 777, no luck. put the file back in the same directly and got the data print results just fine.

Any reason why this might occur? nothing changes but the form action. and once I do that all data is lost when I try to test it.

It is really odd.

Comment: is `ROOT DIR` the web root or just the root folder of your application?

Comment: the web root is the (ROOT DIR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing it

```
<form id="test" action="../includes/action.php"  method="POST" >
```

Means "yoursite.com/../includes/action.php" and it won't work.

Try doing:

```
<form id="test" action="/includes/action.php"  method="POST" >
```